# Dynamical systems on integers

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, dynamical-systems

Let $80\mid M$, where $M$ is a positive integer such that $gcd(3,M)=1$.  Then how can we prove the following statement: for any given $N\in \mathbb{N}$,  where $$\gcd(N,M)=1,0\leq N\leq M-1$$ there exists some $i\in \mathbb{N}$ such that either
$$3^iN\mod M\in \{0,1,\cdots, 79\}$$
or
$$M-(3^iN\mod M)\in \{0,1,\cdots, 79\}.$$
It is easy to check that when $M=160,320,\cdots$, the above statement is always correct. But for a general proof. It is not easy. Intuitively, I think this problem has some connection to the group theory, in particular the cyclic group.

Comment: Is there a condition missing, such as $\gcd(3, M) = 1$? Otherwise, if I'm not mistaken, with $M = 80(3^4)$ and $N = 83$, there's no solution for $i$ that meets your conditions.

Comment: @ John Omielan. Many thanks for your comment. I do miss this key condition. I fix it.

Comment: You're welcome. However, there are still counter-examples, e.g., $M = 3^8 - 1 = 80(82) = 6560$ and $N = \frac{6M  + 1}{7} = 5623$. Please provide more context for your problem, e.g., any other unstated conditions, the source of the problem, how it's connected to the "dynamical-systems" tag you used, any particular significance to $80$, why you think the statement is true (if you're not sure, then please state that), the attempts you have made to check on the problem further yourself, etc.

Comment: @John Omielan. Thanks for your elegant counterexample. My original motivation is similar to the famous ``3X+1`` problem. We can view  x/2 or 3x+1 as a dynamical operation. The 3X+1 problem states that eventually the dynamical orbit is $4\to 2\to 1$. In other words, we will always get $1$ eventually. The above is my toy example.

Comment: My original problem is that  is there  any uniform constant $c$ such that for  any   given natural numbers $N$ $M$,   $(N,M)=1,0\leq N\leq M-1$, under the two operations $3N\mod M$ and $N(M-1)\mod M$ (the reflection can be viewed as a multiplication $M-1$), the number $N$ will eventually hit the interval $[0,c]$. We can view the orbit of $N$ as a dynamical orbit. It is well-known that Terence Tao proved that for  the "most natural numbers" in certain sense, the $3X+1$ problem is correct. So, if my problem is not correct, then for what kind of numbers satisfying the properties I mention?

Comment: $80$ is not too special, I just consider the orbit of $N$, which eventually becomes a small number. However, for the bound of this small number, I am not so sure.